# Create a schema that has some dynamic keys and some static keys with zod

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zod

I want to achieve a result similar to this type, but using zod.

```
type a = {
  [key: string]: string;
  name: string;
  surname: string;
}
```

So a type that has some static fields but accepts other dynamic ones.

I know about `z.record(z.string(), z.string())`, but it seems like it can only recreate the case where the type only has dynamic keys, as in:

```
type zod = {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

I also tried using merge:

```
const dynamicPropertiesSchema = z.record(z.string());

export const PersonSchema = z.object({
  anagraphics: z.object({
    name: z.string(),
    surname: z.string(),
  }).merge(dynamicPropertiesSchema),
  notes: z.array(z.string()),
});
```

But I get the following error highlighting the .merge() parameter:

`Argument of type 'ZodRecord<ZodString, ZodString>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyZodObject'.   Type 'ZodRecord<ZodString, ZodString>' is missing the following properties from type 'ZodObject<any, any, any, { [x: string]: any; }, { [x: string]: any; }>': _cached, _getCached, shape, strict, and 14 more.ts(2345)`

So, all in all, I'd like something like this:

```
const mixedSchema = z.object({
  z.record(z.string(), z.string()),
  name: z.string(),
  surname: z.string(),
});
```

Would this be able to be achieved somehow?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the correct way to accomplish this would be to use an intersection:

```
const schema = z.intersection(z.object({
    name: z.string(),
    surname: z.string(),    
}), z.record(z.string(), z.string()));

type T = z.infer<typeof schema>;
//   ^? { name: string; surname: string } & Record<string, string>
```

Similar to how you would do it with plain TS types:

```
type T = { name: string; surname: string } & Record<string, string>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBALzgMyhEcBECIBNMDcAsAFCkDGEAdgM7w3kAWApiAIZwC8iAdMFTGZQazcjGDUAFAh4QARgCtRMSQG9ScTXCpsQzAFy86UfgHNJASgA0GrTQCuUHXsMzjZy1a1xSAX2u8UKLQuNI87lTmAW4wJpGWFhbEZCQwAJ5gzHAAKly8-MhCADzpmRDIcAws7AB8BEA)